# Always order factors by first appearance

Tags: r, dataframe, default

I know that `df$x = fct_inorder(df$x)` will order `x` by first appearance. Invariably when I load data, this is also my preferred order. So I end up having to call `fct_inorder` many times, once for each factor. Is there a way to change default behavior, so that instead of being alphabetized, R always orders factor levels by first appearance?

Comment: I guess it could be, at least to some extent, done by overriding `base::factor`, `base::as.factor`, etc. But while that would suit your purposes, it may definitely have serious side effects elsewhere as many functions and packages may rely on alphabetizing.

Comment: How are you loading the data? Is it data built into a package? Using `read.csv`?

Comment: R does _not_ change the order of data entered as factor. You need to be more clear about what is happening that is not expected. Need an example.

Comment: @G5W Does it matter? Most commonly I end up calling `read.table`, sometimes `read.csv`.